# Filter "Similar questions" by "Tags" while writing a question

Tags: feature-request, filtering, similar-questions

While writing a question, won't it be better to automatically filter the "Similar questions" window by the "Tags" under the question?

When I was writing a question regarding C language, the "Similar questions" displayed many similar questions in Javascript, not C. Such situations may occur across different sites of SE network.

I'm requesting this feature because it will make a better alert of any possible duplicates at the time of writing questions in this box.